# Make HoF synonym a separate tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

[higher-order-functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-functions) is currently a synonym for [functional-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming).  This is inaccurate; there is a significant overlap, however:

1. Functional Programming is a much broader topic.
2. HoFs are present in some decidedly non-FP languages and can be used in largely non-functional code.
3. HoFs are a significant enough concept to have their own tag.

Comment: How many questions would you expect would be applicable for the HoF tag? Can you show any examples?

Comment: @SimonForsberg They're both my questions, but they'd work: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107468/summations-and-products-in-f http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108231/summations-and-products-and-factorials-oh-my